# Should a field be left null or initialized to a default value when fetching data from an API in null safe Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

Should I set a value to every null fields when retrieving something something from an api? Or should I keep them null and check when displaying them if they aren't null?

Ex:

```
  factory Geo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Geo(
    type: json["type"] == null ? 'Point' : json["type"],
    coordinates: json["coordinates"] == null ? [] : List<double>.from(json["coordinates"].map((x) => double.tryParse(x))),
  );
```

or

```
  factory Geo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Geo(
    type: json["type"] == null ? null : json["type"],
    coordinates: json["coordinates"] == null ? null : List<double>.from(json["coordinates"].map((x) => double.tryParse(x))),
  );
```

Edit --> or should I be doing this in an other way like this maybe?

```
  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Location(
      geo: json["geo"] = Geo.fromJson(json["geo"]),
      city: json["city"] = json["city"],
      country: json["country"] = json["country"],
      area: json["area"] = json["area"],
    );
  }
```

Comment: But for every value I'm planning to show the user I should set a value right?

Comment: Also, if your class is non nullable, this `type: json["type"] == null ? null : json["type"],` wont work.

Comment: So I should make my variables nullable when initializing them in my class? It is weird because some of them are null even though I didn't specify they have to be. I'm on flutter 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null-safety in Dart is *not* a campaign to get rid of `null`. `null` is a valid information.

Take the easiest example: does my wife want a pizza? Seems like an easy true/false question. Until you consider that "I haven't asked her yet" is indeed a real world state that is just as valid.

So no, you should not replace all your `null` values with something else. You would lose information.

So again: null safety does not mean you get rid of the null value. It means you no longer get *surprised* by the null value.

If you have values that can legitimately be `null`, then let them be.

You got improved compiler support now to make sure you don't drop the ball and mistakenly assume they are always non-null. That's great. Be happy about it.